# Initiate template driven form / form's object typescript Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component with a template driven form, which I have an object `myObj` that gets the values from the form's fields. The component looks something like:

```
export class a {
    myObj:any;
    ..
    ..
    initiateObj():void {
        this.myObj = {
           x:"",
           y:"",
           z:[],
           xy: []
       };
     }


    ..
    ..

    reset():void {
       this.initiateObj();
    }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.initiateObj();
   }
```

The view looks something like:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
   <input ... [(ngModel)]="myObj.x" #myInput="ngModel" />
   <input ... [(ngModel)]="myObj.y" #myInput1="ngModel" />

   <select ... [(ngModel)]="myObj.z">
   </select>
   ..
   .. 

  <button ....     (click)="submit()">
  <button ....     (click)="reset()">
</form>
```

when the component initiates the values in the console of myObj are:

x:" ",

y:" ",

z:[],

etc.

However, when I fill the form - even if I not fill the form, just click the reset button, the values of `myObj` in the console will be:

x: null,

y: null,

z:[null]

..

which causes an error when I need to use `myObj` again (when I need to use the form again).

When the component initiates for the first time, the values are Ok. But once I click the reset button, the values become null.

I tried to use in the view one way binding - [ngModel] instead of [(ngModel)], and then when I click reset it's Ok, but then `myObj` will not get the values from the form - because it's one way binding. So I have to use two way bindings. But then when I click on reset the values of the object become null.

I also tried something like:

```
<button .... (click)="myForm.reset(); reset();"
```

or in the component with `ViewChild` to do `this.myForm.reset()`

But it didn't resolve the issue.

Is there a way to unbind the object from the [(ngModel)] when reset?

Or any other way to solve this issue ? (and still use two way bindings [(ngModel)] )

It's a form that should be used few times before leave / initiate again the component.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Please create a [mcve], all codeparts necessary isn't complete. Try and make a StackBlitz, there you will at the same time know how much code you need to show to make it a [mcve] ;)

Answer (score 0):

Declare your class like this way

```
export class initiateObj {
  x: '';
  y: '';
  z: [];
  xy: string;
  constructor(options: any = {}) {
    this.x = options.x || null;
    this.y = options.y || null;
    this.z = options.z || null;
    this.xy = options.xy || null;
  }
}

 reset(): void {
    this.myObj = new initiateObj();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myObj = new initiateObj();
  }
```